# How to prove that these two sets are equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think I can prove that
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i\setminus\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} A_i
=(A_1\setminus A_2)\cup(A_2\setminus A_3)\cup\cdots\cup(A_{n-1}\setminus A_n)\cup(A_n\setminus A_1).$$
so,I think maybe there has(treat infinity as a circle):
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\setminus\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n=(A_1\setminus A_2)\cup(A_2\setminus A_3)\cup\cdots$$
but I dot't know how to prove it.

Comment: False: Take an increasing sequence , for instance.

Comment: Why do you think they're equal?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As often, the step from finite to infinite has problems. If you look at the proof of the finite case, you'll see that you actually need the "circle" nature of the right hand side, given by the last term "closing the cycle". There is no such "closing part" in the infinite case. That means if you have an element in $A_2, A_3, A_4,...$, but not in $A_1$, then it will be in the left side set of the (supposed) equality, but not in the right side set. Again, this can be in the infinite case because there is no part that looks like $\ldots\backslash A_1$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, what you wrote is not quite true. However, it can be fixed as follows:
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\setminus\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (A_{n+1}\setminus A_n)\cup (A_n\setminus A_{n+1})
$$
The proof is this. If $x$ is in at least one of the $A_n$, but not all of the $A_n$, then there must exist an $i$ such that $x\in A_i$, and a $j$ such that $x\notin A_j$.  Furthermore,  $i$ and $j$ can be chosen to be consecutive natural numbers. To see this, imagine coloring all natural numbers for which $x\in A_i$ blue, and calling all natural numbers $j$ for which $x\notin A_j$ red. It is easy to see there must exist a red number next to a blue number.

However, we have no control over whether $i=j+1$ or $j=i+1$. This is why we need a union of $(A_{n+1}\setminus A_n)\cup (A_n\setminus A_{n+1})$, instead of just $A_{n+1}\setminus A_n$. In the finite case, you could "go around the circle" to force $i=j+1$.